# Designing Organizational structure

Tags: database

This question was asked in a interview. Design a organizational structure, where an employee can have direct reports, and indirect reports (that is reportees of reportee). The design should be such that, in a single query it should be able to retrieve either direct or indirect reportees or both.

I suggested,

```
Employee
----------
id 
name

Reportee
------
emp_id FK
reportee_id FK
isDirect
```

The interviewer said the optimistic solution is

```
Employee
-------
id
name
reporting_path like (a>b>c)
```

Adding additional table, takes more space, but query will be executed faster. I said that due to string matching, the path based approach is bad and yields bad performance.

So which approach is optimistic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interviewer's approach is dumb because it does not use referential integrity.

For a purely hierarchical model (an employee cannot report to more than one boss), then this is the best approach:

```
create table employees (
  employee_id int primary key,
  name varchar(whatever) not null,
  supervisor_id int null references employees(employee_id)
);

insert into employees (employee_id, name, supervisor_id) values 
(1, 'Big Boss Bill', null),
(2, 'Vice President Victor', 1),
(3, 'Underling Ulysses', 2),
(4, 'Subordinate Sam', 2);
```

You can then use [Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to query reports.

Some example queries here:

http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/02/trees-paths-recursive-cte-postgresql.html